How do I know a Locator really points to an existing element?
I am using #playwright-java , learning by doing, first time user.
I have been attracted by the ease of use seen in the demos.
However, when facing a complex website it turns out it needs more trial&&error than expected.
Now, when I put the xpath or full xpath I do not get my info :/
Tried (different) xpaths in full page, then in target frame, got them using my browser devtools.
Is there a way to know if a Locator is really points to an existing element ?
When I get an exception, the line numbers are (I believe) for typescript and do not help.
When using debugger, Locator object has xpath attribute set, else a frame reference.
I tried to use the recorder but the selector presented is based on the value.
For a value I get:
page.frameLocator("#legacy-iframe-3755").getByRole(AriaRole.CELL, new FrameLocator.GetByRoleOptions().setName("xxxxx €")).click();
This wont work in my context (#legacy-iframe-3755 is not a stable value).
Unless there is a way to get a solid (unmutable) xpath from a locator gotten from a value.
Here is the stacktrace, for documentation.
"The expression is not a legal expression" is rather poor.
The guilty code happens in the loop to address the different options of the select droplist.
It is :
Locator locatorTableauPositions = page.locator(Constantes.Positions.IDENTIFIANT_TABLEAU); 
// "xpath=//table@id=tabPTR"
int nombrePositions = locatorTableauPositions.locator("tr").count();    // BOOM


Is my locator not pointing to the target table ?
Is this not the way to get the rows count ?
com.microsoft.playwright.PlaywrightException: Error {
  message='Document.evaluate: The expression is not a legal expression
queryAll@debugger eval code:41:25
_queryEngineAll@debugger eval code:4949:49
querySelectorAll@debugger eval code:4936:30
@debugger eval code line 226 > eval:4:23
evaluate@debugger eval code:228:17
@debugger eval code:1:44

  name='Error
  stack='Error: Document.evaluate: The expression is not a legal expression
queryAll@debugger eval code:41:25
_queryEngineAll@debugger eval code:4949:49
querySelectorAll@debugger eval code:4936:30
@debugger eval code line 226 > eval:4:23
evaluate@debugger eval code:228:17
@debugger eval code:1:44

    at checkException (/tmp/playwright-java-5991555694620122335/package/lib/server/firefox/ffExecutionContext.js:111:121)
    at FFExecutionContext.evaluateWithArguments (/tmp/playwright-java-5991555694620122335/package/lib/server/firefox/ffExecutionContext.js:82:5)
    at async LongStandingScope._race (/tmp/playwright-java-5991555694620122335/package/lib/utils/manualPromise.js:96:14)
    at async evaluateExpression (/tmp/playwright-java-5991555694620122335/package/lib/server/javascript.js:241:12)
    at async FrameSelectors.queryCount (/tmp/playwright-java-5991555694620122335/package/lib/server/frameSelectors.js:74:12)
    at async Frame.queryCount (/tmp/playwright-java-5991555694620122335/package/lib/server/frames.js:736:12)
    at async FrameDispatcher.queryCount (/tmp/playwright-java-5991555694620122335/package/lib/server/dispatchers/frameDispatcher.js:135:14)
    at async LongStandingScope._race (/tmp/playwright-java-5991555694620122335/package/lib/utils/manualPromise.js:96:14)
    at async FrameDispatcher._handleCommand (/tmp/playwright-java-5991555694620122335/package/lib/server/dispatchers/dispatcher.js:96:14)
    at async DispatcherConnection.dispatch (/tmp/playwright-java-5991555694620122335/package/lib/server/dispatchers/dispatcher.js:361:22)
}
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.WaitableResult.get(WaitableResult.java:56)
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.ChannelOwner.runUntil(ChannelOwner.java:120)
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.Connection.sendMessage(Connection.java:130)
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.ChannelOwner.sendMessage(ChannelOwner.java:106)
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.FrameImpl.queryCount(FrameImpl.java:1116)
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.LocatorImpl.count(LocatorImpl.java:165)
    at org.wadael.bourdirconnect.PortefeuilleExtracteur.extraitPortefeuille(PortefeuilleExtracteur.java:153)
    at org.wadael.bourdirconnect.PortefeuilleExtracteur.extraitPortefeuille(PortefeuilleExtracteur.java:35)
    at LeTest.estCeQuilYADuContenu(LeTest.java:33)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:765)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:218)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:139)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1597)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1597)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:198)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:169)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:93)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:103)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:85)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingLauncher.execute(DelegatingLauncher.java:47)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:63)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: com.microsoft.playwright.impl.DriverException: Error {
  message='Document.evaluate: The expression is not a legal expression
queryAll@debugger eval code:41:25
_queryEngineAll@debugger eval code:4949:49
querySelectorAll@debugger eval code:4936:30
@debugger eval code line 226 > eval:4:23
evaluate@debugger eval code:228:17
@debugger eval code:1:44

  name='Error
  stack='Error: Document.evaluate: The expression is not a legal expression
queryAll@debugger eval code:41:25
_queryEngineAll@debugger eval code:4949:49
querySelectorAll@debugger eval code:4936:30
@debugger eval code line 226 > eval:4:23
evaluate@debugger eval code:228:17
@debugger eval code:1:44

    at checkException (/tmp/playwright-java-5991555694620122335/package/lib/server/firefox/ffExecutionContext.js:111:121)
    at FFExecutionContext.evaluateWithArguments (/tmp/playwright-java-5991555694620122335/package/lib/server/firefox/ffExecutionContext.js:82:5)
    at async LongStandingScope._race (/tmp/playwright-java-5991555694620122335/package/lib/utils/manualPromise.js:96:14)
    at async evaluateExpression (/tmp/playwright-java-5991555694620122335/package/lib/server/javascript.js:241:12)
    at async FrameSelectors.queryCount (/tmp/playwright-java-5991555694620122335/package/lib/server/frameSelectors.js:74:12)
    at async Frame.queryCount (/tmp/playwright-java-5991555694620122335/package/lib/server/frames.js:736:12)
    at async FrameDispatcher.queryCount (/tmp/playwright-java-5991555694620122335/package/lib/server/dispatchers/frameDispatcher.js:135:14)
    at async LongStandingScope._race (/tmp/playwright-java-5991555694620122335/package/lib/utils/manualPromise.js:96:14)
    at async FrameDispatcher._handleCommand (/tmp/playwright-java-5991555694620122335/package/lib/server/dispatchers/dispatcher.js:96:14)
    at async DispatcherConnection.dispatch (/tmp/playwright-java-5991555694620122335/package/lib/server/dispatchers/dispatcher.js:361:22)
}
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.Connection.dispatch(Connection.java:259)
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.Connection.processOneMessage(Connection.java:211)
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.ChannelOwner.runUntil(ChannelOwner.java:118)
    ... 75 more
 

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: not equal but was: <0>

    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.build(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:152)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.buildAndThrow(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotEquals.failEqual(AssertNotEquals.java:277)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotEquals.assertNotEquals(AssertNotEquals.java:94)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotEquals.assertNotEquals(AssertNotEquals.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotEquals(Assertions.java:1981)
    at LeTest.estCeQuilYADuContenu(LeTest.java:41)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1597)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1597)


Process finished with exit code 255

Context:
I am trying to get my info from my broker account.
The code will be made public later although it will only be useful to the broker customers, mostly :fra: customers I believe. So I also pleased myself not coding in English this time.
Page has many frames and the info I am looking for is gotten from a sub page (php).
The iframe name changes over time so locator obtained from recorder is not possible for all infos
I looped in the frames, looked for the html declaring the select, then rewrote the different xpath for:

adapting to the frame html root (I loaded it in my browser and used devtools)
adapting to the row number

I tried accessing via xpath either from page or a shorter one from the frame.
Thank you for your time and expertise

Turns out I misused selectOption.
Because the first option has value="1" I started my loop incorrectly at 1
for (int j = 0; j < options.count(); j++) {
nc.selectOption( new SelectOption().setIndex(j)) ;
however, it does not make the stacktrace more comprehensible.
Will open an issue about this

Playwright has very specific ways of interacting with frames which you don't appear to be using. Playwright doesn't give you direct access to elements, you sort of look at a faux version of the page which points at the website. https://playwright.dev/docs/frames

@Monofuse Thank you.
Here is the quite simple project I learned playwright with+for
https://github.com/wadael/BourDirConnect
afterward I reckon some exceptions happens because depending on the selection in the droplist, the table was not existing (an empty account)

As a company dev heavy we've just changed all the automated stuff to playwright because its that good and all the the devs can help

I will certainly use playwright java again. I was trying to locate a non existing élément (depending on the option selected). pebkac. However, looking at java objets in debugger could be more informative
